python pandas change flip data frame dementions
i am using python and pandas and having problem transforming a json object into a pandas dataframe
i have a JSON object:
data = {
 "f1": "test",
 "f2":[{"f3": 1, "f4": "f4_1" }, {"f3": 2, "f4": "f4_2" }] 
}

i want to get a data frame:
f3|f4    | temp_col
=========================
1 |"f4_1"| {"f1": "test"}
2 |"f4_2"| {"f1": "test"}

temp_col is a name i provide
how do i do that with pandas?
i have tried using json_normalize but that did not work

there is f1 value only test in real data json?

Use json_normalize and create temp_col in list comprehension:
df = (pd.json_normalize(data, 'f2')
        .assign(temp_col = lambda x:  [{'f1': data['f1']} for i in x.index]))
print (df)
   f3    f4        temp_col
0   1  f4_1  {'f1': 'test'}
1   2  f4_2  {'f1': 'test'}

Or change input data for dicts in temp_col column:
data['temp_col'] = {'f1': data['f1']}
print (data)
{'f1': 'test', 'f2': [{'f3': 1, 'f4': 'f4_1'}, {'f3': 2, 'f4': 'f4_2'}], 
 'temp_col': {'f1': 'test'}}

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'f2', ['temp_col'])
print (df)
   f3    f4        temp_col
0   1  f4_1  {'f1': 'test'}
1   2  f4_2  {'f1': 'test'}

Without dictionaries solution should be:
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'f2', ['f1'])
print (df)
   f3    f4    f1
0   1  f4_1  test
1   2  f4_2  test


A simple approach, pop the key to use as main dictionary/DataFrame, then assign the remaining dictionary to temp_col:
d = data.copy() # optional, just to preserve the original dictionary

df = pd.DataFrame(d.pop('f2'))
df['temp_col'] = pd.Series([d]*len(df))

NB. if you do not need data afterwards, you can't directly use it rather than the copy d.
Output:
   f3    f4        temp_col
0   1  f4_1  {'f1': 'test'}
1   2  f4_2  {'f1': 'test'}

